# Big Love Series Finale - Barb's New Car Scene - How'd they get such clean dialogue?

Tags: car, dialogue-recording, driving

So, I was watching the series finale to Big Love last night and the three sister wives were riding down the highway in, I think, a Mini Cooper with the top dropped down. The dialogue was absolutely clear. It does not look like they used ADR here. The actors were quite still so I really think we're hearing audio that was captured on location with well-hidden Lavs on each of the actresses.  At one point, Barb's hair is all over her face and I can only imagine that she did not brush it out of her eyes because they may have been instructed to not move at all so as to not risk the dreaded cloth noise running over the mics.

[Here's the link to the clip.](http://www.hbo.com/big-love?autoplay=true&cmpid=ABC655#/big-love/episodes/5/53-where-men-and-mountains-meet/video/ep-53-scene-clip-on-the-road-.html/eNrjcmbOUM-PSXHMS8ypLMlMDkhMT-VLzE1lzmcu1CzLTEnNh8k45+eVpFaUsDFyMjKySSeWluQX5CRW2pYUlaayMQIAUmYXOA==)

How many of you guys were thinking about sound during that scene? I imagine that they did a great job filtering out wind noise and engine noise in post. Or do you think it's possible to get great audio in that scene with minimal work in post?

Answer (score 2):

Hi
My opinion on this is that they actually used booms with good windshields. For the most part the car would have been on a trailer/flatbed truck (I think you can actually see part of this truck at 0.39, above the drivers door) and this would mean that there could, potentially, be one or two boom ops on the truck as well. Using good boom technique and shotguns it's possible to get close sound and reduce the background sound.

Comment: I used a Rycote Windshield kit on a feature film for the first time. It captured location audio quite well on Location. But I never had anything as challenging as capturing audio in a moving car with the top down. your answer makes a lot of sense, tho! Thanks, Simon!

Answer (score 2):

I also think it is not ADR. If you listen closely, you can hear the wind noise/rumble around the lines of dialogue. There isn't much of the very high frequencies in the dialogue, suggesting that it has been recorded using a lot of wind protection. They have probably used fixed microphones from below, combined with lav mics.

They have probably edited out everything except the dialogue when the car is moving, and then they have probably used eq, noise reduction and volume to make it sound properly.

Comment: I agree with the combination of mics. If not fixed then certainly Boom and Lav. It was so distracting to watch this scene and trying to imagine what I'd have to do if I was given this task. A part of me believes that the final mix is probably 70% lav with 30% boom. Thanks, Morten!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surprised if they used a couple Sanken CUB mics mounted directly on the sun visors of the car for the front two actors. An old trick used by many production mixers. I do think they also boom when filming on a flatbed though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the weird grunting sound at 00.11

Comment: That's Nicki scoffing at the start of her line. Or some mic that was really close to her at the start of the line like a Lav. I doubt it was a boom that caught that sound as she would have to eat the boom to get that sound.
